# Get sum of multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to get the sum of all numeric values in my array for each designated month. Ideally, it would return the following format.

April

total = 22

March

total = 'sum'

```
Array
    (
        [April] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
                [3] => 
                [4] => 3
                [5] => 
                [6] => 2
                [7] => 6
                [8] => 3
                [9] => 2
            )

        [March] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3.19198
                [1] => 2.52219
                [2] => 3.40053
                [3] => 2.42639
                [4] => 3.92301
                [5] => 3.23758
                [6] => 3.22457
                [7] => 2.62855
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/array_sum) on each of the sub-arrays using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$result = array_map('array_sum', $data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [April] => 22
    [March] => 24.5548
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/143419)